# Tensorflow stuck when evaluating the result of tf.gradients

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm trying to evaluate the gradient of my output wrt an input using my network. The network works perfectly fine during the forward prop, so no issues there. The code for the gradients looks like this:

```
images, labels = inputs(train_dir,
                        True,
                        batch_size,
                        num_batches,
                        one_hot_labels=True)
predictions = InterpolNet(images)
restorer = tf.train.Saver()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    restorer.restore(sess, checkpoint_dir)
    print 'Get grads'
    grad_output = np.zeros((1,h,w,3), dtype=np.float32)
    grad_output[0,0,0,0] = 1
    grad = tf.gradients(predictions, images, grad_output)
    print grad[0]
    res = grad[0].eval()
```

So basically I declare the inputs to my net with the `inputs` function, I get my model through the call to `InterpolNet` and I restore the checkpoint with the latest training weights. If I now do a `sess.run(predictions, feed_dict=feed_dict)` where in feed_dict I put some input, everything is fine and the output of the run is the expected output of the net.

When I try to get the gradients instead (with the code above), the program apparently gets stuck on the `res = grad[0].eval()` line (0% GPU usage and no noticeable CPU usage). The `print grad[0]` prints what looks like the correct tensor:

`Tensor("gradients/conv1/conv1_1/Conv2D_grad/Conv2DBackpropInput:0", shape=(1, 128, 384, 6), dtype=float32)`

but  the code doesn't reach the next line. Am I doing something wrong? Using the `grad_output` doesn't seem to impact on the issue. Just as a reference, I'm trying to reimplement the paper from https://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.06041v2.pdf

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have queues? Typical hang is when you dequeue from an empty queue. A way to diagnose is to enable operation_timeout_in_ms as described [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2130#issuecomment-215180165)

Comment: Actually yes, I do and you're right, setting up the timeout clearly shows that that's the problem. I will try to change the way I'm feeding the input to the net so I don't get stuck in the queue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out from Yaroslav comment, I was getting stuck in a data generation queue inside my `inputs` function.

What I did is to change the variable `images` from the output of the queue to a placeholder: `images = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(1, h, w, 6))`.

This allowed me to compute the symbolic gradients with the `tf.gradients` and then use the `feed_dict` in the `grad[0].eval()` to feed the net with a numpy array containing the data instead of employing the queue (which is the one I used in the training).

Now everything works!